# Delphi 7 - which unit declares TProperty?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Sorry to ask something so basic, but I just can't find it.

I found some example code which seems to do exactly what I want, but it doesn't include a `uses` clause.

---

```
procedure FilterProps(Sender: TObject; Prop: TProperty; var Result: boolean);
```

`undeclared indentifier: TProperty`

Comment: Could you post a link to the example code you found?

Comment: I don't have D7 here, but I was unable to find this type in the VCL and RTL source code for D2010. It doesn't strike me as something that would be removed between D7 and D2010, so I doubt you'll find it in the units that ship with D7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by the author of the code sample when I managed to contact him was unit `PropertyList`. That compiles for me.

Answer (score 2):

TProperty is part of the D2010 RTTI property information. The D7 RTTI information is in the unit TypInfo.

Answer (score 1):

The Delphi 7 help does not mention TProperty. Maybe the sample code declares the TProperty itself?

If TProperty has something to do with property editors etc., then maybe you can try the DesignIntf or DesignEditors unit.

Comment: It is something to do with property editors, but those suggestions don't seem to help :-(